# How to write partitioned json with filename in Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs, partitioning

I want to write a spark Dataframe into aws s3 as json format.

The dataframe has this columns:
`id| year| month| day| location_id| data|`

I want each row to be a single json with the following path:
`s3://bucket/json_data/year=YYYY/month=MM/day=DD/location_id=LOCATION/{id}.json`

Currently I have the partitioned directories but I'm missing the `{id}.json`.
An example path of a file is the following:

`s3://bucket/json_data/year=2020/month=10/day=20/location_id=3/part-00194-a1042870-4376-43c2-aea1-8d74ef6fc4de.c000.json`

The code to obtain the previous filename is:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite")\
        .format("json")\
        .partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "location_id")\
        .save("s3://bucket/json_data")
```

How can I assign a particular name like the id name? Obtaining the following filename.
`s3://bucket/json_data/year=2020/month=10/day=20/location_id=3/record_0000001.json`

**Note:**
I want to avoid adding the id as another partition key and obtaining
`s3://bucket/json_data/year=2020/month=10/day=20/location_id=3/id=record_0000001/part-###.json`.

This is because I need to reference the clean path from another service.